# Nginx shows Cent OS welcome page instead of nginx welcome page

Tags: nginx, centos

I have recently installed `nginx` in `Cent OS` and page loads successfully. But it shows Cent OS welcome Page instead of Nginx welcome page. Picture attached
[Cent OS welcome Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qxll.png)

Comment: Generally people replace the welcome page with useful content, so whatever's on the welcome page generally isn't very important. I'm not sure how this is really a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many Linux distributions ship a custom `index.html` in the default web root directory. 
nginx has a default server configuration with a root of `/usr/share/nginx/html` and the page you are seeing is the `index.html` in that directory.

Sometimes it will be served by a separate config file (particularly, httpd uses a file called `welcome.conf`), but in nginx, you just need to change the default file or add your own servers in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.